# StreamBridge resetting Kafka headers

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am using Spring Cloud Stream 3.2.2 to produce Cloud Event messages to a kafka topic.  According to the Cloud Event spec when using kafka the headers should use a prefix of "ce_" [cloud event spec](https://github.com/cloudevents/spec/blob/v1.0.2/cloudevents/bindings/kafka-protocol-binding.md#3231-property-names).  Here is what my producer looks like:

```
      this.streamBridge.send(
      "myBinding-out-0",
      CloudEventMessageBuilder.withData(event)
          .setSource("my-source")
          .setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
          .setSpecVersion("1.0")
          .setType("myType")
          .build(),
      MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

In my configuration I have my binder set to kafka `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.myBinding-out-0.binder=kafka`.  When I publish a message to kafka the headers always end up with the prefix `ce-` instead of `ce_`.  I have also tried using `.build("ce_")` and also tried setting the header `target-protocol` to `kafka` but neither worked.

When I debugged this I found that [line 219 of StreamBridge](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/3.2.x/core/spring-cloud-stream/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/function/StreamBridge.java#L219) resets `target-protocol` which looks like it causes the prefix to be changed to `ce-`.

How can I get the Cloud Event headers to be named correctly for Kafka?

Answer (score 0):

That is ok, since your message did not come from Kafka. The framework should automatically adjust your headers to `ce_` once it is writing it to Kafka. If that is not the case please [raise an issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/issues). Given that CloudEvents support is rather new and not the most popular module, there may still be some minor issues like this

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Actually I am writing this message to Kafka so I will raise an issue.